# How to create a library for C# functions in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I am building my own Xamarin.forms app. I have this C# function -

```
int compare(int a, int b) {
  if (a > b) {
     return a;
  }
  else {
     return b;
  }
}
```

And I want this function for all of my pages in Xamarin. Please tell me how to access this function from all pages and where should I define it?.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you create an xamarin.forms application, you already have a NetStandard2.0 Library, which is included in all of your plattform specific applications (Android, iOS, UWP). So if you add your code there, the code is available everywhere in your application. Just keep in mind to make the method/class public

Comment: For that specific function? Discard it and use `Math.Max()` from the standard library.

Comment: Yes, I didn't know that function, thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don need to create a library.There are a lot of methods,the easyiest method is that you could define a static method in your `App.xaml.cs` and then you could call it in all pages.

For example:

define the method in your `App.xaml.cs`:

```
 public static int compare(int a,int b)
    {
        if (a > b)
        {
            return a;
        }
        else
        {
            return b;
        }
    }
```

then you can call it in your other pages:

```
int result = App.compare(2,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of answering the question:

- To make a library to bundle into your Xamarin.Forms project, create a new .Net Standard *Class Library* project in your Xamarin solution, and add a project reference to that new library in your Xamarin.Forms project.

But, realistically, you don't need to do this with a Forms solution because the purpose of the Forms project is to act as a single shared library across your platform deployments. Any kind of shared helper code should be static classes or dependency injections in your Forms project.

Also in this specific instance, just use `Math.Max(a, b)` instead.

Comment: Thanks to you also king-of-kingeth. The solution you suggested is applicable if there are many functions. But I have only one, so I have accepted Leo Zhu - MSFT's solution.

Comment: And also thanks for the Math.Max() function.